# I want to draw a charts/ graph (e.g. bar chart) in nodejs using typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

i already used pkg =https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-charts-node ,by which I'm able to draw charts in NodeJS(javascipt).
but when i tried same code in NodeJS(typescript) it didn't work.
so please suggest me the solution by which i can implement the charts in NodeJS(typescript).

here typescript structure(all files are typescript) followed in NodeJS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does the package declare its types? TypeScript requires them, unless disabled, checking its [yarn page](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/package/google-charts-node) seems that it does not.

Could you also provide us with any errors reported on the execution?

Comment: i used as below :
-- import * as  GoogleChartsNode from 'google-charts-node'
-- let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ ........])

in 2nd line , 'google' shows with red underline, while hover on it , cant find name google

Answer (score 0):

So I found my own answer after lots of research.
I found this pkg (chartjs-node-canvas) , which working for me in both NodeJS with JavaScript and typescript.

for JavaScript follow the same instruction given in pkg.
for typescript use : import { ChartJSNodeCanvas } from 'chartjs-node-canvas'